# Custom control on Google maps and street view

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Currently I'm able to create the Google maps custom controls with api-v3. But when I drag the pegman and open street view my custom controls will be gone or bring to back. (I am not sure).

So my question is, how can I create global custom controls which display both at Google map
 and Google street view. It means those controllers will always display no mater you on Map or Street view.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue,all I did is set the panorama and the map controls:

```
 var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
 var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

 homeControlDiv.index = 1;
 panorama.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);
 map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);
```